# ObjectiveC: How to stop a music player from another view in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio-player

I would like to stop my music playing from another view by using delegates. I already have that setup and i know there is this option...

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    [player stop]; ///(my players name here and command to stop the player)
}
```

However i do not want to use that function because i have the music playing throughout. I have already added code to ensure my player does not overlap. But when i do want to stop my music i want to do so in a different view. I have tried the `'[player stop];'` function when the delegate is called but it does not work.

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advanced...

**EDIT**

**HERE IS THE CODE FOR MY OPTIONS PAGE.H FILE:**

```
@protocol onHandlerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)off:(BOOL)success;
- (void)on:(BOOL)success;
-(void)volumeValueChange:(UISlider *)sender;

@end

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface OptionsPage : UIViewController{


    IBOutlet UISlider *VolumeSlider;
    NSTimer *VolumeTimer;
    IBOutlet UISwitch *onoroffmusic;

}
-(IBAction) UIBarButtonItem:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) SwitchMusic:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)changevolume:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISwitch *onoroffmusic;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<onHandlerDelegate> delegatePpty1;


@end
```

**HERE IS MY OPTIONS PAGE .M FILE:**

```
#import "OptionsPage.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface OptionsPage ()

@end


@implementation OptionsPage
@synthesize onoroffmusic;
@synthesize delegatePpty1;

- (IBAction)changevolume:(id)sender{
    int volume = VolumeSlider.value;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:volume] forKey:@"volume"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [[self delegatePpty1]volumeValueChange:(VolumeSlider)];
}
-(IBAction) SwitchMusic:(id)sender{
    if (onoroffmusic.on) {
        [[self delegatePpty1] on:YES];
        printf("done");
        onoroffmusic.on = YES;
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"off"];
        [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"on"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
    else {
        /// do nothing
        [[self delegatePpty1] off:YES];
        printf("off");
        onoroffmusic.on = NO;
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"on"];
        [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"off"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        ViewController *home = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [home.player stop];

    }
}



-(IBAction) UIBarButtonItem:(id)sender{

    ViewController *Backbutton = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:Backbutton animated:YES completion:nil];

}





- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    VolumeSlider.value = 0.3;
  NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSObject * object = [prefs valueForKey:@"volume"];
    if(object == nil){
        VolumeSlider.value = 0.3;
    }
    else{
        VolumeSlider.value = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"volume"] intValue];

    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL restoredBoolValue2 = [[defaults2 objectForKey:@"off"] boolValue];
        BOOL restoredBoolValue1 = [[defaults2 objectForKey:@"on"] boolValue];
    if (restoredBoolValue2) {
        ////donothing
        onoroffmusic.on = FALSE;
    }
    if (restoredBoolValue1) {
        ////donothing
        onoroffmusic.on = TRUE;
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Within the two files i declare a delegate and my switches. Now just to receive that delegate in my view controller:

MY VIEWCONNTROLLER .H FILE:

```
#import "OptionsPage.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <onHandlerDelegate>{
    AVAudioPlayer *player;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;

@end
```

HERE IS MY .M FILE:

Firstly I

```
@synthesize player;
```

Then check if my delegates have been called by using:

```
-(void)volumeValueChange:(UISlider *)sender
{

    if (sender.value > 0.3) {
        player.volume = sender.value;

    }
    else{
        player.volume = 0.3;
    }
}
-(void)on:(BOOL)success{
    NSLog(@"Delegate Method Called");
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"mykey1"];
    [self play];
    [player play];
}

-(void)off:(BOOL)success{
    NSLog(@"Delegate Method Called");
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"mykey1"];
    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"mykey"];
    [player stop];
    player = nil;
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"music"];


}
```

I then load the `bool` value of my `nsuserdefults` by using this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"mykey"] == nil ) {

        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"music"] == nil) {

        [self play];
    }

    }
}
NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL restoredBoolValue2 = [[defaults2 objectForKey:@"mykey"] boolValue];
if (restoredBoolValue2) {
    ////donothing
    [player stop];
}
BOOL restoredBoolValue1 = [[defaults2 objectForKey:@"mykey1"] boolValue];
if (restoredBoolValue1){
    [self play];
}
```

And i have my play `void` function

```
-(void)play{

     if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"music"] == nil) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Music.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    NSError *error;
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    player.numberOfLoops = -1;
        [player play];
        player.volume = 0.3;
        player.currentTime = 0.0;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"-" forKey:@"music"];


     }
     else {

         [player stop];
     }

}
```

and lastly in my app delegate.m file i :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"music"];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make player a property and stop it like this:

```
[anotherView.player stop];
```

Comment: the code you have given me works however i have my setting view and my home view and the home view is playing the music. I leave the home view and go to the settings view and turn the music off which works. so i turn it back on and re-enter the home view. The music is playing again which is good but when i re-enter the settings view and turn off the music it does nothing. The music continues

Comment: well, it may be caused by different reasons, i cannot be certain without seeing your code

Comment: However, you better tie the music off any view and make it separate singletone class

Comment: It may be like this [[MusicPlayer sharedMusicPlayer] startPlayingMusic]; and [[MusicPlayer sharedMusicPlayer] stop];

Comment: I'm pretty sure such an architecture is much better and easier to maintain. You will always have access to the music player no matter what view you're in

Comment: just a quick guess. try to synthesize the player like this @synthesize player = player;

Comment: do you have anymore suggestions

Answer (score -1):

First you need to change `onHandlerDelegate` from `strong` to `weak` because it is a delegate.

Secondly you need an instance of `OptionsPage` on the second view controller and you need to implement the delegate and do `optionPage.delegate = self` after it this will work.